# Easy brightness control

Tags: 12.10, brightness, applet, widgets

I came from linux mint they had a really nice applet for adjusting the brightness. Is there something like that, or can it be done by hotkeys or something? I am on ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used this myself, but there is `indicator-brightness` which can be found [here](https://launchpad.net/~indicator-brightness/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).